# Calculate $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi }{4}} = \frac{{1 - \sqrt 2 \cos x}}{{1 - t{g^2}x}} $

Tags: calculus

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi }{4}}  = \frac{{1 - \sqrt 2 \cos x}}{{1 - t{g^2}x}}
$$

I can replace variable next:

$$\left| \begin{array}{l}y = x - \frac{\pi }{4}\\x = y + \frac{\pi }{4}\end{array} \right|
$$

and represent

$$1 - t{g^2}x = (1 - tgx)(1 + tgx)
$$

But what i can do with numerator?

Comment: You are in right path. Now, put $1-\sqrt{2} \cos (x- \frac {\pi}4)$ and expand this as $\cos (A-B)= \cos A \cos B+\sin A \sin B$ .Now, note that, $\cos \frac {\pi}4 =\sin \frac {\pi}4 =\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$. I think you can do this from here.

Comment: @Clayton, Where you found $t$!

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%281-sqrt%282%29cos+x%29%2F%281-%28tan+x%29%5E2%29+as+x+to+pi%2F4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{1-\sqrt{2}\cos x}{1-\tan^2x} = \frac{1-\sqrt{2}\cos x}{1-\left(\sec^2x-1\right)} = \frac{1-\sqrt{2}\cos x}{2\cos^2x-1}\cos^2 x = \frac{1-\sqrt{2}\cos x}{(\sqrt{2}\cos x-1)(\sqrt{2}\cos x+1)}\cos^2x
$$
thus we get
$$
\frac{1-\sqrt{2}\cos x}{1-\tan^2x} = \frac{-1}{(\sqrt{2}\cos x+1)}\cos^2x
$$
and then
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi/4} \frac{-1}{(\sqrt{2}\cos x+1)}\cos^2x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{-1}{2}\frac{2}{4}=-\frac{1}{4}
$$